# Multiplying 2 Polynomials using Classes I've created (JAVA)_

Tags: java, methods

Hey guys I'm having trouble with a method I'm tying to write in java. The method is supposed to multiply 2 polynomials (a class I made) together. A polynomial consists of Terms (another class I made) Here is the code:

```
public Polynomial multiplyBy(Polynomial anotherPoly)    //EXTRA CREDIT
{
    Polynomial thePoly = new Polynomial();
    int polyTermNum = 0; //keeps track of which term in anotherPoly is being multiplied

    if(anotherPoly == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The polynomial cannot be null");
    else
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < theAL.size(); i++)
        {
            while(polyTermNum < anotherPoly.theAL.size())
            {
                thePoly.insert(theAL.get(i).multiplyBy(anotherPoly.theAL.get(polyTermNum))); //multiplies 2 terms from theAL and anotherPoly
                polyTermNum++;
            }
        polyTermNum = 0; //resets which term in anotherPoly is being multiplied
        }

        return thePoly;
    }
}
```

I know for sure that the multiplyBy method of Term and the insert method of Polynomial are both working as they pass my instructors test when used outside of the method I'm working on. From what I can tell it is throwing illegal argument exceptions whenever I use this new method because Term is set up to throw an exception if it is null. But I'm having trouble figuring out why there are any terms that are null, when my instructors tester doesn't pass null through.

Assuming that all the methods used within this method are working, does anyone see why I would be getting any terms that are null?

edit: wanted to clarify that theAL is an ArrayList that contains Terms

edit2: it ended up being something wrong with my Term's multiplyBy method that was causing it to throw IllegalArgumentExceptions incorrectly so my code was okay, just had to fix something else.

Comment: Write a few test cases and try to debug it. Otherwise it's hard to say anything without seeing your complete source code, you'll need to post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). From the code snippet you're posted I don't see any obvious NPE. But who knows, since it's not the complete code, who knows what can or cannot be `null` here.

Comment: @lexicore it ended up being something silly in my Term's multiplyBy method that was causing it to throw the exception. Took me an hour to figure it out. Still trying to learn how to debug with eclipse. Almost gave up but glad I got it lol